# Which one is more idiomatic and why?

Tags: word-usage

My question is that which sentence is  preferable in terms of using: tend to , really or rather, because by me in the dictionaries I can use each of them .

1. Younger siblings tend to favor the creative fields such as music, art, or writing.
2. Younger siblings really favor the creative fields such as music, art, or writing.
3. Younger siblings rather favor the creative fields such as music, art, or writing.

Comment: Hello Marek, you have been here long enough to  know that we are no translation service.... These sentences are quite different in meaning. How about at least giving some context and a few thoughts of your own?

Comment: Marek, to avoid any misunderstandings, you should edit your Q and ask, "which one is more idiomatic and why?"

Answer (score 2):

I prefer sentence 1. “Tend” means that something often happens even though sometimes it might not (Oxford online [defines it](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tend) to mean “regularly or frequently behave in a particular way or have a certain characteristic”) which seems to be your intended meaning.

Sentences 2 and 3 can be read with similar meanings, but the adverbs there could also be read as referring to *how much* younger siblings favour the creative fields rather than *how often*: in other words, 3 has a possible reading of “all younger siblings mildly favour the creative fields” instead of “a majority of younger siblings favour (to some unspecified extent) the creative fields”. This second reading is by no means impossible, but if this is what you mean I recommend option 1 as a less ambiguous alternative.

“Really” in sentence 2 is also stronger than “rather” or “tend to”.